# How to update Spring Batch status on unexpected shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobs

I'm implementing a service that would reject job requests from being processed if an existing job is running.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a way to tell the difference between a job that is actively running and a job that ended due to an unexpected shutdown like turning Tomcat off. The statuses in the tables are the same with status = STARTED and exit_code = UNKNOWN.

```
        Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("MY_JOB");
```

Is there a way to tell the two apart or implementation that would change active job statuses to maybe ABANDONED?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no way, by just looking at the database, to distinguish between a job that is effectively running and a job that has been abruptly killed (in both cases, the status is `STARTED`).

What you need to do is, **in addition to** checking status in the database, find a way to see if a job is effectively running. This really depends on how you run your jobs. For example, if you run your jobs in separate JVMs, you can write some code that checks if there is a JVM currently running your job. If you deploy your jobs to Kubernetes, you could ask Kubernetes if there is a pod currently running your job, etc.

However, if you can identify the execution that has been abruptly stopped for which the status has been stuck at `STARTED` (because Spring Batch did not have a chance to update its status to `FAILED` with a graceful shutdown), then you can update the status manually to `ABANDONED` and set its `END_TIME` to a non null value. This way, `JobExplorer#findRunningExecutions` will not return it anymore as a running execution.

Comment: Can't edit, but be advised that the correct wording of the status is `ABANDONED`.